# Unable to switch team in itunes connect

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, iphone-developer-program

I've been stuck for a few days trying to switch teams in itunes connect.

I was a member of multiple teams, one of which had an expired membership (I'm not the Team Agent on any of them). And from the drop down menu I didn't had the switch team option.

I left all teams except the one I need to work with in https://developer.apple.com/account/ but itunes connect remains stuck in the same team (24-48h now since I did that).

I tried contacting Apple via the 'contact us' form but they haven't replied yet. Has anybody faced this issue?

[image: stuck in a team of which I'm no longer a member]

Comment: Try to get a new invite from the team you want to be part of. And if you are already a member there then maybe they have to remove you and then add you again. Not sure if it helps but at least you could try that :)

Comment: Thanks @JensSchwarzer, I guess that is my next/last alternative.

Comment: I'm having the same issue, no solution?

Comment: @Srdjan I didn't find a solution to leave the "old team", I guess emailing Apple Support and working with them to be removed manually would work. I'm just too lazy to do that since I can access my new team now, so I'll just leave it there. The solution to access the new team was, as suggested, for the admin to remove and then invite me again. Now I switched to that new team profile and everything works normally. Hope this helps.

Comment: @Fdo Yes, as usual everything works fine, but I didn't know :) Old team admin removed me and after 15-20 minutes, I could access the new team.

Answer (score 2):

We had same issue but may not be same cause.
One email address/username for App Store and Enterprise account.

Usually the drop down in top right showed a list of accounts.

Then suddenly it only showed one.

I found out it was because I had logged into iTunes Connect directly which only shows App Store account.

https://itunesconnect.apple.com/

To see both accounts, in the top right drop down, log in through Apple Developer Portal first

https://developer.apple.com/account

Both account appeared in top right list under the name.

As you swap accounts using the login the iTunes Account menu option on the developer portal only appears for Non Enterprise accounts ie App Store ones.

Comment: Hi. I have the same issue. I see enterprise + self account on developer.apple.com, but only enterprise at appstoreconnect.apple.com . How to solve this?

Comment: I've tried to exit from enterprise team, and when press "appstore connect" it always opens https://appstoreconnect.apple.com/WebObjects/iTunesConnect.woa/ra/gettingstarted